# How to plot two different 3D lines in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I'm trying to plot two different lines in python using this code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(x1, y1, z1, 'gray')
ax.scatter3D(x1, y1, z1, c=z1, cmap='Greens');

ax.plot3D(x2, y2, z2, 'red')
ax.scatter3D(x2, y2, z2, c=z2, cmap='Blues');
```

and I get this output:

[image: Output]

It connects the first line to the new one. Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "it connects the first line to the new one" - to me it looks like it's only plotting the second line, implying that `x1`, `y1`, and `z1` are empty. Are you certain this is not the case?

Comment: yes, from this perspective i chosen it looks like a V shape. they are supposed to be separated (perhaps like this: \ /)

Comment: Can you include the code which generates `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`, `z1`, and `z2`?